# How to assign the max value across mulptiple fields to a single column in a select statement using MS-Access-2010 SQL?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access-2010

I have multiple columns in a table but I only want the highest value from the columns to be selected in a sql.

Example Info:

```
D1     D2     D3     D4
-----  -----  -----  -----
3      2      150    5
1      3      20     10
```

Output needs to be:

MaxPower
150
20

Anyone know a good way to do this? A single sql would be preferred but vba would work also.

Comment: Does the data above represent two rows, each with four columns? And you want the highest value in the row, for each row? Does the row have a primary key not shown above?

Comment: Thank you daemon_x for formatting the table for me. How exactly did you do that? I can never seem to get it to accept spacing.

Comment: you can simply paste the table as a code (using `{}` button as you already know), so then you will see just what you write and it looks more colorful ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select max(v) as maggiore from (
select id,d1 as v from table
union all
select id,d2 from table
union all
select id,d3 from table
union all
select id,d4 from table
) as t
group by id
```

Comment: Thank you. Will there be any issues using this type of query to Update an existing table? Also I'm assuming the id field can be supplemented with other columns (like 3 separate columns instead of an id column) correct?

Comment: Sorry. I don't understand what kind of update you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

How about `select max(max(d1,d2), max(d3,d4)) from table`?

Comment: This doesn't work. I believe max (just like all of the other aggregate functions ie avg, min etc...) only works for a single column.

Comment: Ok so then you can simulate one with a case expression.

Comment: Nope. Access doesn't support `Case` (unless it's brand new in 2010, & I don't think it is...).

Comment: Sorry. I'm more used to SQL Server T-SQL.

Comment: Docs say Case can only be used in VBA context. However Choose isn't documented to have this restriction. Do logical expressions have a numeric value in Access SQL? If so we can use Choose(1 + (a > b), b, a) for max(a, b) if true is 1 and false is zero.